# Setting QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer

I'm coming from a C# background and still getting my head around c++ and Qt smart pointers.  This should be a basic question:

In myClass.h

```
QSharedPointer<AccessFlags> m_flags;
```

In myClass.cpp I'm trying to set (is set the correct word?) the m_flags pointer

```
if(m_flags.isNull())
    m_flags = new AccessFlags();


class AccessFlags{
public:
     QHash<QString,int> flags;
     AccessFlags();  //The dictionary is setup in the constructor
};
```

The compiler complains "no match for 'operator=' in..
How do I set the pointer?

Comment: Why is there a `.` after `m_flags`?

Comment: typo.  Didn't copy and paste code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to assign a raw pointer to a `QSharedPointer` in the line

```
m_flags = new AccessFlags();
```

You probably want something like

```
m_flags = QSharedPointer<AccessFlags>(new AccessFlags);
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead QSharedPointer if you work with modern C++11 compiler (e.g. GCC 4.6 or above and MSVC 10.0).

First of all, it's a standard and second thing, you could use [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) to init your pointer which can be faster! (For example, in MSVS2010/2012 allocation occurs only once for make_shared instead two allocations: one for new and one for internal counter).

Comment: There is a static `create` method, which makes the same as `std::make_shared`, so no gain here. And if the whole project uses QT classes, there is no reason to create a mess with standard classes and then   have a pain converting one class objects to another.

Comment: For the record: `create` method is only available in Qt5